# Seleniumで要素が表示されているのに、StaleElementReferenceExceptionが発生する

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

SeleniumでimplicitlyWaitで待っていると要素が表示されても、`StaleElementReferenceException`が発生してしまいます。
なぜなのでしょうか?

下記のようなコードを実行するとsubmit後の画面が再描画された直後にエラーが起きてしまいます。

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 10秒間待機させる
driver.get("http://example.com/app");

driver.findElement(new By.ById("user")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(new By.ById("password")).sendKeys("my_password");
driver.findElement(new By.ById("submit-button")).click();
// 要素が表示されるのに時間がかかる (約5~6秒)
driver.findElement(new By.ByClassName("menu-button")).click(); 
// ここでStaleElementReferenceExceptionが起きる
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家SOでもいくつか解答例はありましたが、明確な手法としては、一定時間待機するか、ループして対応する方法で解決しているようです。

こちらが参考になるかも知れません。

How To Handle Stale Element Reference Exception Selenium Webdriver
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.jp/2015/02/how-to-handle-stale-element-reference.html